# If a cell equals to this date, then filter through another sheet and grab that cell that has the same date

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, vlookup, google-sheets-dates

When you input a date in sheet 1, I want it to automatically grab data from sheet 2 and input text that matches that date back into sheet 1

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **`VLOOKUP`** it if today's date is in **A** column of **Sheet1**:

```
=VLOOKUP(TODAY(), 'Sheet1'!A:B, 2, 0)
```